# Ansible Task to Generate an AWS SSM Activation Code with Multiple Tags

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-ssm

In an effort to support dynamic key-value pairs in Ansible, I am looking to update an existing role which creates an AWS SSM activation to allow the passing of arbitrary tags during runtime.

So far, I have tried leveraging the following Ansible constructs, all to no success: `list` variable, `dict` variable, `loop`, `with_dict`, `with_items` and native Python `dict` methods.

Here are some details on my Ansible environment:

- Ansible version: 2.9.23
- AWS CLI version: 1.18.147
- Python version: 3.7.10
- AWS SSM command reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/create-activation.html

The current role/command with hard-coded tags looks like so:

```
- name: Generate SSM activation code and ID
  command: |
    aws ssm create-activation
    --tags "Key=key1,Value=value1" "Key=key2,Value=value2"
  register: ssm_activation_code
```

The idea is to update it to look like so:

```
 name: Generate SSM activation code and ID
  command: |
    aws ssm create-activation
    --tags "Key={{ item.key }},Value={{ item.value }}"
  register: ssm_activation_code
  with_items: "{{ aws_ssm_instance_tags }}"
```

And have the consumer of the role pass tags like so:

```
- role: ansible-role-aws-sm-agent
  vars:
    aws_ssm_instance_tags: {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      .....
    }
```

The issue with all loop structures is that the task runs once for each key-value pair, resulting in multiple SSM activations, which is incorrect. Instead, I would like to pass all tags in a single execution. I am happy to provide any additional details if needed. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is my opinion that trying to coerce an already structured input back down into the "pseudo-grammar" used by awscli is the road to ruin when [`--cli-input-json`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-skeleton.html) exists if one wishes to specify multiple arguments, or `--tags` to just provide the tags

```yaml
- name: Generate SSM activation code and ID
  command: >-
    aws ssm create-activation
    --tags {{ cli_tags | to_json | quote }}
  register: ssm_activation_code
  vars:
    cli_tags: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for k, v in aws_ssm_instance_tags.items() -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.append({"Key": k, "Value": v}) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

which given your example input generates the shlex-ed cmd:

```yaml
 ["aws", "ssm", "create-activation", "--tags", "[{\"Key\": \"key1\", \"Value\": \"value1\"}, {\"Key\": \"key2\", \"Value\": \"value2\"}]"]
```

be aware: I updated your code snippet because there was a typo: `command: |` preserves linebreaks, and thus the shell command that originally was there would end up being *two* commands, since bash uses newlines to terminate commands in normal cases

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I understand your thought process. After making the suggested change, I get the following response: 
```fatal: [<ip_address_redacted>]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "aws ssm create-activation --cli-input-json '[{\"Value\": \"value1\", \"Key\": \"key1\"}, {\"Value\": \"value2\", \"Key\": \"key2\"}]'", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'aws': b'aws'", "rc": 2}```
I think this is because `--cli-input-json` requires a file as input? 
**Note**: I am using AWS CLI version 1.18.147.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, is it not? The task needs the fully-qualified location of `aws` or to modify the `PATH` in the `environment:` of at least that one task to include the dir in which `aws` lives

Comment: You are right - I completely misunderstood the error. I am now debugging:
`fatal: [<ip_address_redacted>]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "ssm", "create-activation", "--cli-input-json", "[{\"Value\": \"value1\", \"Key\": \"key1\"}, {\"Value\": \"value2\", \"Key\": \"key2\"}]"], "delta": "0:00:00.559151", "end": "2021-10-13 22:24:15.224743", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 255, "start": "2021-10-13 22:24:14.665592", "stderr": "\n'list' object has no attribute 'keys'", "stderr_lines": ["", "'list' object has no attribute 'keys'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Comment: Your `cli_tags` logic was spot on. Thank you. To fix the error above, I had to use the `--tags` arguments instead of `cli-input-json`. I will mark this solved. If it helps others, I can also post a copy of the working code. Thanks again. Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'm **so sorry** -- that's what I get for "coding in a textarea" :-( the `--cli-input-json` version is for providing _all_ arguments, and thus would have worked if I had made `set results = {"Tags": []}` and then populated that `Tags` list. I updated the answer and I'm glad to hear you got it to work despite my mistake

Answer (score 0):

A working copy of the code on the Ansible role:

```
- name: Generate SSM activation code and ID
  command: >-
    aws ssm create-activation
    --tags {{ cli_tags | to_json | quote }}
  register: ssm_activation
  vars:
    cli_tags: >-
      {%- set results = [] -%}
      {%- for k, v in aws_ssm_instance_tags.items() -%}
      {%-   set _ = results.append({"Key": k, "Value": v}) -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ results }}
```

And the code on the Ansible playbook which calls the role:

```
aws_ssm_instance_tags: {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    .....
}
```

A sincere thanks to **mdaniel** for helping me resolve this in a timely manner.